# How to use Stanford Sentiment Analysis Dataset

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to use Stanford Sentiment Analysis Dataset to do some sentiment analysis research.  I download the dataset [enter link description here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/stanfordSentimentTreebank.zip)
from http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/index.html . After reading the readme file, I still have some confusion.

First question, In "50446" line of dictionary.txt file, it shows the  "**phrase ids**" of this sentence is "**No.226166**", So when I search in sentiment_lable.txt file, I find in the "226168" line, the "**sentiment values**" of phrase "**No.226166**" is **0.69444**. But In "50445" line of **dictionary.txt file**, this sentence is equal to the sentence in  "50446" line. But this sentence has different "sentiment values" in the sentiment_lable.txt file, why?!!!

Second question, In some sentiment analysis paper, they not only use full-length sentence in training sentence to train model, but also use  **labelled phrases that occur as subparts of the training sentences** to train model. But I find some phrase in  **dictionary.txt** file such as line 2 and 3 which are useless, should I use these useless phrases to train my model?

Answer (score 1):

The format of the dictionary.txt file is

```
<Phrase>|<ID>
```

The format of sentiment_labels.txt is

```
<Phrase ID>|<Score>
```

So for instance

```
id: 50445 phrase: control of both his medium and his message
score: .777

id: 50446 phrase: controlled display of murderous vulnerability ensures that malice has a very human face
score: .444
```